# AutoIt exe gets killed by antivirus

Tags: autoit, antivirus

I compiled an AutoIt script to an .exe file. When I give this program to another user, their antivirus detects it as a virus and kills it.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How can I avoid killing AutoIT .exe by antivirus.

Assuming it does not classify as malicious:

1. White-list the executable (or folder containing it) in antivirus program.
2. [File a false-positive report](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/34658-are-my-autoit-exes-really-infected/) with concerning antivirus program's vendor.
3. Change antivirus software.

Resulting executable is the AutoIt script appended to an interpreter (no actual compiling). Incompetent vendors flag the interpreter instead of the script. False-positive reports usually solve this (until that vendor flags the next malicious AutoIt script, hence #3).